# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, android, comparator, comparable

In this method I want to sort Float values in ascending order, for this I wrote the class Confidence Comparator (see sourcecode below)

```
public final PriorityQueue<Result> getResults(){
    PriorityQueue outputQueue = new PriorityQueue(createOutputQueue());

    for (int i =0; i<results.length+1;i++){
        Result res = new Result(labels.get(i), results[i]);
        outputQueue.add(res);
    }
    return outputQueue;

}
private final PriorityQueue<Result> createOutputQueue(){
    Comparator<Float> comparator = new ConfidenceComparator();
    return new PriorityQueue(labels.size(),comparator);
}
```

ConfidenceComparator:

```
public class ConfidenceComparator implements Comparator<Float> {     

public int compare(Float x, Float y) {                            

   return x.compareTo(y); }
```

This throws the exception:

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: jannik.weber.com.brueckenklassifikator.classifier.Result cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"
```

after two confidences have been added to the `outputQueue` in the `getResults()` method.

I also tried implementing the comparable Interface in the Results class because it's sorting the values in their natural order:

```
public class Result implements Comparable{
private String result;
private float confidence;

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Result other = (Result) o;
    return this.confidence.compareTo(other.confidence);
}
```

But it shows the error 
`"Cannot resolve method compareTo(float)"`

Comment: `confidence` is a *primitive*. Primitives don't have methods. Try [`Float.compare(this.confidence, other.confidence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-).

Comment: *FYI:* Do not use *raw* generics. Change `implements Comparable` to `implements Comparable<Result>`

Comment: Instead of `this.confidence.compareTo(other.confidence)` of course.

Comment: Sorry but where would I put this? So I should use the comparable interface rather than the Comparator?

Comment: *FYI:* Do not use *raw* generics. Change all `PriorityQueue` to `PriorityQueue<Result>`

Comment: Whichever way you go: Do not use *raw* generics!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing `Float`s, you are comparing `Result`s with a float value inside them.
So should be `Comparable<Result>` indeed.

Then try this instead, as confidence is not an object, in your compareTo:

```
return Float.compare(this.confidence, other.confidence);
```

With the complete code:

```
public class Result implements Comparable<Result> {
    private String result;
    private float confidence;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Result other) {
        return Float.compare(this.confidence, other.confidence);
    }
}
```